# Flutter : StreamSink<dynamic> can't be returned from the function 'chuckDataSink' because it has a return type of StreamSink<Response<chuckResponse>>?

Tags: flutter, stream-builder

By migrating to Flutter 2, I am getting the below error.

lib/blocs/chuck_category_bloc.dart:12:7: Error: A value of type 'StreamSink?' can't be returned from a function with return type 'StreamSink<Response>?'.

- 'StreamSink' is from 'dart:async'.
- 'Response' is from 'package:upgrade_noyelling/networking/Response.dart' ('lib/networking/Response.dart').
- 'chuckCategories' is from 'package:upgrade_noyelling/models/chuck_categories.dart' ('lib/models/chuck_categories.dart').
  _chuckListController?.sink;
  ^
  lib/blocs/chuck_category_bloc.dart:15:7: Error: A value of type 'Stream?' can't be returned from a function with return type 'Stream<Response>?'.
- 'Stream' is from 'dart:async'.
- 'Response' is from 'package:upgrade_noyelling/networking/Response.dart' ('lib/networking/Response.dart').
- 'chuckCategories' is from 'package:upgrade_noyelling/models/chuck_categories.dart' ('lib/models/chuck_categories.dart').
  _chuckListController?.stream;
  ^

Below is the code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:upgrade_noyelling/models/chuck_response.dart';
import 'package:upgrade_noyelling/networking/Response.dart';
import 'package:upgrade_noyelling/repository/chuck_repository.dart';

class ChuckBloc {
   ChuckRepository ? _chuckRepository;
   StreamController ?  _chuckDataController;
   bool ? _isStreaming;

  StreamSink<Response<chuckResponse>>? get chuckDataSink =>
      _chuckDataController.sink;

  Stream<Response<chuckResponse>> get chuckDataStream =>
      _chuckDataController!.stream;

  ChuckBloc(String category) {
    _chuckDataController = StreamController<Response<chuckResponse>>();
    _chuckRepository = ChuckRepository();
    _isStreaming = true;
    fetchChuckyJoke(category);
  }

  fetchChuckyJoke(String category) async {
    chuckDataSink!.add(Response.loading('Getting a Chucky joke!'));
    try {
      chuckResponse chuckJoke = await _chuckRepository!.fetchChuckJoke(category);
      if (_isStreaming!) chuckDataSink!.add(Response.completed(chuckJoke));
    } catch (e) {
      if (_isStreaming!) chuckDataSink!.add(Response.error(e.toString()));
      print(e);
    }
  }

  dispose() {
    _isStreaming = false;
    _chuckDataController?.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69347907

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem that you have after upgrading to flutter 2. I managed to solve this problem by using:

```
    class ChuckBloc {
       ChuckRepository ? _chuckRepository;
       final  _chuckDataController = StreamController<Response<chuckResponse>>();
       bool ? _isStreaming;

       StreamSink<Response<chuckResponse>> get chuckDataSink =>_chuckDataController.sink;

       Stream<Response<chuckResponse>> get chuckDataStream =>_chuckDataController!.stream;

       ChuckBloc(String category) {
          _chuckRepository = ChuckRepository();
          _isStreaming = true;
          fetchChuckyJoke(category);
       }
       
       //the rest of your code here...
       
    }
```

You can removed the "?" on the chuckDataSink too since it won't be null

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by turning off null safety by setting the SDK constraints in the project's pubspec.yaml file. Earlier, my sdk was "2.12.0 <3.0.0" so I switched it to "2.7.0 <3.0.0". Here's the link to the resource.

https://we-launch.com/turn-off-null-safety-in-flutter/

Answer (score -2):

dart 2.12 is some extrict with null values

so

The _chuckDataController not is inicializate from begin to used

```
ChuckBloc {
final _chuckDataController PublishSubject<Response<chuckResponse>>();
StreamSink<Response<chuckResponse>> get chuckDataSink =>   _chuckDataController.sink;
```