# A value of type 'Stream<dynamic>' can't be returned from the function because it has a return type of 'Stream<Color>'

Tags: flutter, stream

After migrating to flutter 2, the following section of code no longer works:

```
class ColorBloc extends BlocBase {
// streams of Color
  StreamController _streamListController = StreamController<Color>.broadcast();
// sink
  Sink get colorSink => _streamListController.sink;
// stream
  Stream<Color> get colorStream => _streamListController.stream;


// function to change the color
  changeColor(String chosenColour) {
    switch(chosenColour) {
      case 'blackTheme':
        {
          colorSink.add(AppState.blackTheme);
        }
        break;

      case 'blueTheme':
        {
          colorSink.add(AppState.blueTheme);
        }
        break;

      case 'greenTheme':
        {
          colorSink.add(AppState.greenTheme);
        }
        break;

      case 'redTheme':
        {
          colorSink.add(AppState.redTheme);
        }
        break;

      case 'whiteTheme':
        {
          colorSink.add(AppState.whiteTheme);
        }
        break;
    }

  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    _streamListController.close();
  }
}
```

The issue being with this line:

```
 Stream<Color> get colorStream => _streamListController.stream;
```

And the reason given is:

```
A value of type 'Stream<dynamic>' can't be returned from the function 'colorStream' because it has a return type of 'Stream<Color>'.
```

But I am not really sure what this means, or how to go about trying to resolve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to edit this line `StreamController _streamListController = StreamController<Color>.broadcast();` to `StreamController<Color> _streamListController = StreamController<Color>.broadcast();`

The error says that `colorStream` is a `Stream` of `Color` but you are giving it a `Stream` of `dynamic` and `dynamic` could be anything. So it's a wrong type assignment. Stream of course is generic.

Comment: Perfect, looks good.  Thanks Moneer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the Type Color to your StreamController like so:

```
StreamController<Color> _streamListController = StreamController<Color>.broadcast();
```